# Using QPainter to display live camera feed

Tags: c++, qt

I am just curious if we can use `QPainter` to display the live camera output. If so can anyone tell me how will be the implementation.
I already used it with `QLabel` like this:

```
cM2 = new QCamera(this);
cV2 = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
cM2->setViewfinder(cV2);
cBox2 = new QVBoxLayout();
cBox2->addWidget(cV2);
ui->label_2->setLayout(cBox2);
cM2->start();
```

Comment: code looks ok. What problems are you having?

Comment: HI Joseph, I just want to know if i can use QPainter. Basically i want to rotate the live feed from camera which i cant do in here, however i can implement it using QPainter widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you propose to use the `QPainter` so I can't really comment on that.

However, one option might be to repackage the `QCameraViewfinder` widget up in a [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) and corresponding [`QGraphicsScene`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) and rotate the item within the scene.

```
QGraphicsView view;
QGraphicsScene scene;

/*
 * Add the view finder widget to the scene and keep hold of the
 * proxy returned.
 */
auto *proxy = scene.addWidget(my_camera_view_finder);

/*
 * Use the proxy to rotate the view finder by 90 degrees.
 */
proxy->setRotation(90.0);
view.setScene(&scene);
view.show();
```

Note that there will probably be performance implications due to painting via the proxy.  This method also assumes that the `QCameraViewfinder` uses Qt to perform its painting logic rather than something more direct such as OpenGL -- otherwise it won't work as expected.

The above logic could probably be packaged up as something fairly self-contained such as...

```
class rotated_widget: public QGraphicsView {
  using super = QGraphicsView;
public:
  explicit rotated_widget (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : super(parent)
    , m_widget(nullptr)
    , m_proxy(nullptr)
    , m_degrees(0.0)
    {
      setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
    }
  virtual void set_widget (QWidget *widget)
    {
      scene()->clear();
      m_proxy = nullptr;
      if ((m_widget = widget)) {
        m_proxy = scene()->addWidget(m_widget);
        m_proxy->setRotation(m_degrees);
        fixup();
      }
    }
  virtual void set_angle (double degrees)
    {
      m_degrees = degrees;
      if (m_proxy) {
        m_proxy->setRotation(m_degrees);
        fixup();
      }
    }
  virtual QSize sizeHint () const override
    {
      return(sceneRect().size().toSize());
    }
private:
  void fixup ()
    {
      setSceneRect(scene()->itemsBoundingRect());
    }
  QWidget              *m_widget;
  QGraphicsProxyWidget *m_proxy;
  double                m_degrees;
};
```

Then use as...

```
cV2 = new QCameraViewfinder;
auto *rotated = new rotated_widget;
rotated->set_widget(cV2);
rotated->set_angle(90.0);
```